# How to set global property for react using esbuild

Tags: reactjs, typescript, esbuild

According to the docs using `define` is the suggested way of setting the env properties for a build.

When I run my app with I get a process is not defined error.

My esconfig is as follows:

```
        await build({
            entryPoints: ['./src/index.tsx'],
            outdir: './build',
            bundle: true,
            incremental: true,
            metafile: true,
            target: 'es6',
            loader: { '.png': 'file' },
            minify: !dev,
            sourcemap: 'inline',
            define: { 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development') },
            plugins: [
                sassPlugin(),
                svg(),
                copy({
                    resolveFrom: 'cwd',
                    assets: {
                        from: ['./public/*'],
                        to: ['./build2/*'],
                    },
                }),
                copy({
                    resolveFrom: 'cwd',
                    assets: {
                        from: ['./public/images/*'],
                        to: ['./build2/images/*'],
                    },
                }),
            ],
            watch: dev
                ? {
                        onRebuild: (error) => {
                            if (error) {
                                console.error(error);
                            } else {
                                console.log('rebuild done');
                            }
                        },
                  }
                : false,
        });
```

I'm also open to other ways of setting global properties to control the configuration.

Comment: you mean when you run this build script or when you run an app that uses the resulting bundle? If the latter then please add your code where you are using `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Comment: I was using the standard way create react app allows you to pass env variables. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/
But as I'm moving away from cra, I just now removed using process.env und came up with my own solution. 
Using process.env never felt right in the first place..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resorted to writing a config/env file before the build starts.
My react app then just needs to know where the env file is located.

```
const config: IEnv = {
    ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'development',
    USE_EMU: process.env.USE_EMU === '1' ? true : false,
    USE_DEV: process.env.USE_DEV === '1' ? true : false,
    VERSION: process.env.VERSION ? process.env.VERSION : 'dev',
};
fs.writeFileSync('src/env.json', JSON.stringify(config), { encoding: 'utf8' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `process is not defined` error because you actually do not define `process` in `define` option, you do define `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

It may be counterintuitively but it is how `define` option is used. It doesn't actually defines variable and just replaces all tokens that look like `define` key with corresponding value.